# Data is saving as array in database - using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, join

My code:

```
         $name = DB::table('users')
            ->join('user_basic_info','users.id','=','user_basic_info.user_id')
            ->where('user_basic_info.user_id',Auth::user()->id)
             ->pluck('user_basic_info.first_name');


           $userProfile['created_by'] = $name;
```

There is field in my database 'created_by' and it's saving like this ["shahzad"] array as a string. I don't know where I am going wrong; it should save as a simple name as string.

Comment: `= $name[0]` then?

Comment: Is `dd($name);`  what you expect it to be? You need to save the model after editing.

Comment: What has this code got to do with a database column called `created_at` containing `["shahzad"]` ?? I would start looking at the code that created these rows

Comment: This question appears to need clarification but has been abandoned, so I am voting to close.